# Google Compute Engine VM stopped by Google. Will not restart

Tags: google-compute-engine

At the end of the Google Cloud trial period, my VM was stopped by Google. This is understandable, but what comes next doesn't seem so. I have now upgraded to a paid account, but I am still unable to restart the VM. Google cloud support will not help turn the VM back on. They've told me that my only support option is to post my issue here on Stackoverflow. It seems odd that a business like Google would rely on outsourcing it's technical support to the people here.

So here I am. I thank you in advance for reading my issue.

The error message is:
"Starting VM instance "myinstance" failed. Error: Google Compute Engine is not ready for use yet in the project. It may take several minutes if Google Compute Engine has just been enabled, or if this is the first time you use Google Compute Engine in the project."

I have tried multiple times over two days and I still get this same error. The one thing Google did check and verify is that my billing is set up correctly. The dashboard shows that the billing is linked to the project that contains this VM.

Can anyone suggest any troubleshooting steps or solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: Hardly anyone can help you on StackExchange. At the [End of the free trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#end) your resources are stopped, and  any data you stored in Compute Engine is lost. You must manually export data from VM instances before the trial period ends.

Comment: They restored it.